# 別のデータフレームの特定の列の紐づけについて教えてください

Tags: python, python3, dataframe

Pythonに詳しい方、教えてください。
Name、Mail、Date、Kounyukingakuからなるデータフレーム(summary)を、groupbyでDate、Kounyukingakuをそれぞれcountとsumで集計したデータフレームがあります。
以下のようなコードで作成しました。

```
summary = brand.groupby('Name').agg(br1_freq = ('Date','count')
, br1_total = ('konyukingaku',"sum"))
```

ここに、元にあった「Mail」を紐づけるためのコードを教えてください。
もしくは、groupbyで集計する際に「Mail」を残す方法があれば教えてください。
よろしくお願いいたします。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 2):

`Mail` 列をインデックスに追加するとよいかと思います。必要に応じて `reset_index()` を行って下さい。

```py
summary = brand.groupby(['Name', 'Mail']).agg(
              br1_freq = ('Date', 'count'),
              br1_total = ('Kounyukingaku', 'sum'))
```

Comment: ありがとうございました！！！